# Using inserting, deleting, updating predicates with a case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a trigger for a table and I am currently trying to perform a different variable assignment dependent on which DLM operation fired the trigger like this:

```
if deleting then
    a := 'x';
    b := 'y';
if inserting then 
    a := 'y';
    b := 'x';
```

Is there some way for me to do this same type of thing but instead using a CASE statement? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you've tried and explain how that failed.

Comment: You could.  You could also just write two separate triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, This can be simplified as

```
a := CASE WHEN deleting THEN 'x' 
          WHEN inserting THEN 'y'
     END;

b := CASE WHEN deleting THEN 'y' 
          WHEN inserting THEN 'x'
     END;
```

But, I dont think that it is simplified. Huh... You can use as per your comfort.